# List names of DLL linked in an arbitrary PE ( EXE ) file

Tags: windows, go, portable-executable

I have stumbled over the task to read the list of DLL files linked to an arbitrary PE executable on Windows. While `debug/pe` was looking promising yet it was bummer to discover:

```
// ImportedLibraries returns the names of all libraries
// referred to by the binary f that are expected to be
// linked with the binary at dynamic link time.
func (f *File) ImportedLibraries() ([]string, error) {
    // TODO
    // cgo -dynimport don't use this for windows PE, so just return.
    return nil, nil
}
```

So is there anything I can use to extract the list of DLLs from an EXE file?

Comment: If you don't mind using a third party application, [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=vs-2019) can do this. This library might work too - https://github.com/Velocidex/go-pe/blob/master/imports.go

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it:

```
package main
import "github.com/Binject/debug/pe"

func main() {
   f, e := pe.Open(`C:\Windows\notepad.exe`)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   a, e := f.ImportedLibraries()
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   for _, s := range a {
      println(s)
   }
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Binject/debug/pe